# How to send a war file on to a Windows machine location through Ant build.xml file

Tags: java, windows, ant, jsch

I have setup an environment where all my process of svn checkout/updating, compiling, making war, creating required environment are done using the Ant `build.xml`. I am also willing to deploy the built war file through the Ant `build.xml`.

I am successful in using the `build.xml` to deploy applications on to a Linux machine using the SCP task for deploying into the Tomcat webapps directory with the below code.

```
<target> <scp trust="true" file="antproject1.war" 
  todir="${tomcat.username}@${tomcat.server}:${tomcat.webapps.dir}" 
  password="${tomcat.password}"/> </target>
```

But I am not aware what task is to be used with what jar files added to the `ANT_HOME`, to send the war file from my local machine to the remote Windows machine.

Comment: Can you install an sFtp server on the windows (http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server) ?

Comment: If sFtp is the only way, then what should be the code to copy.

Comment: Current code should be working

Comment: @BorisPavlović No it won't work. The SCP is a different protocol to FTP(S).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SCP is not natively supported by Windows.

You can install a 3rd party SCP server. Though most good and easy-to-install SCP servers are commercial.

---

Only an FTP (or FTPS) is supported natively, by Windows IIS server in particular.
See *my* guide for [Installing secure FTP server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server).

Once you have an FTP server running, use an [Ant FTP task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html).

```
<ftp server="example.com" userid="username" password="password">
  <fileset dir="path">
    <include name="antproject1.war"/>
  </fileset>
</ftp>
```

For more examples, see [Ant FTP task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html).

Though note that the Ant FTP task does not support TLS/SSL encryption unfortunately. So contrary to recommendation in my guide, you have to allow unencrypted connection to the IIS.

---

If you want to use a secure connection, you have to use [an Ant Exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and run an external FTPS client.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/):

```
<exec executable="winscp.com">
  <arg value="/command"/>
  <arg value="open ftps://username:password@example.com/"/>
  <arg value="put c:\localpath\antproject1.war /remote/path/"/>
  <arg value="exit"/>
</exec>
```

For details, see the [guide to WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

Advantage might be that WinSCP supports the SCP (and SFTP) protocol too. So you might have the same code (except for the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url)) both for Linux SCP/SFTP and Windows FTP/FTPS.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I am able to achieve my requirement with the <ftp> code. Thank you Martin.